# Simulate my keyboard

Tags: code-golf, string, date

I have an issue with my keyboard (more likely an issue with my browser). Some times when I click on a new text field and begin typing all my text comes out backwards.  After a very short amount of time (for the purpose of the challenge we will say it is 10 milliseconds) it resumes typing forwards again.  It seems that at first my cursor does not move when I begin to type so all the letters get inserted at the beginning of the textfield.

For example if I were typing `python` and I typed `pyt` in the first 10 milliseconds the result would be

```
hontyp
```

## Task

Your job is to simulate this behavior in as few bytes as possible.

### Input

You may take input in any reasonable method. You may not however take the input as two separate fields.  The 10 millisecond delay should start when the program begins to allow input.  That is you may have preprocessing to do before input is allowed, which should not be counted towards the 10 milliseconds.

Some leniency is permitted in the timing as long as it averages 10 milliseconds and is off by more than 1 milliseconds no more than 1% of the time on a reasonably speced computer.

### Output

You may output the string in whatever method you see fit.  You may either update live as the user is typing or output the result after you are finished taking input (either by a newline or end of file `^D`).

## Test cases

*Some of these were generated by [this CMC](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36744438#36744438) in The Nineteenth Byte*

```
First 10  | after   | result
bra         in-flak   in-flakarb
ap          ple       plepa
code-       golf      golf-edoc
no          ne        neon
we          st        stew
ai          med       media
draw        back      backward
```

Comment: So answers should figure out themselves what characters were input in the first 10ms? How will this work in languages where the input is frozen as soon as the program starts?

Comment: @Luke 1) Yes. 2) If that is the only way they can take input then they cannot compete.

Comment: ^ That probably rules out a lot of languages

Comment: It is unfortunate.  I don't want this challenge to rule our languages, however I really don't want it to become a trivial string manipulation challenge.

Comment: So many people have keyboard problems on this site xD

Comment: 10 _milliseconds_ is a *very* short time. Did you really mean that?

Comment: @Neil You are probably right, but it is what it is, I'm not in a position to change it at this point.

Comment: @WheatWizard Can you clarify what is meant by *two separate fields*? Am I allowed to use two instances of the command to gather input, one of those being timed?

Answer (score 7):

## VimScript, <strike>48</strike> 47 bytes

Vim has some nice builtins for this. Requires Vim 8.

```viml
se ri|cal timer_start(10,{->execute("se ri&")})
```

Expects text entered in insert mode, a very reasonable input for VimScript. Explanation:

```viml
se ri " short for 'set revins', or 'reverse insert'
cal timer_start(10, " Start a timer that fires after 10ms
                 {->execute("se ri&")}) " Give it a lambda that unsets ri
```

My initial approach, `se ri|sl10m|se ri&`, doesn't work because the text is buffered until after the sleep command, and I couldn't find a way around this.

Answer (score 5):

### HTML (JS), 96 bytes

```html
<input id=i oninput=i.d=i.d||Date.now()+1e3;Date.now()<i.d&&(i.selectionEnd=i.selectionStart=0)>
```

Starts timing for 1s from the first keypress to give you a chance to see it in action.

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), 88 bytes

```js
p=s='',t=+new Date,document.onkeyup=k=>console.log(+new Date-t>9?(s+=k.key)+p:p=k.key+p)
```

#### Demo

The way the snippet is working, you'll need to **click inside its frame** so that it gets focus *after* clicking on the *Run* button and *before* you can start typing.

There's no way to do that in less that 10ms. So, I've set the delay to 1 second in this demo -- and even so, you'd better hurry.

```js
p=s='',t=+new Date,document.onkeyup=k=>console.log(+new Date-t>999?(s+=k.key)+p:p=k.key+p)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Processing, <s>167</s> <s>165</s> 146 bytes

```processing
String a="",b="";long m=0;void setup(){size(9,9);}void draw(){m=m<1?millis():m;println(b+a);}void keyTyped(){if(millis()-m>9)b+=key;else a=key+a;}
```

Takes input as keystrokes and outputs to the console. It updates every frame.

#### Explanation

```processing
String a="",b="";                // a contains the reversed (in the 10 milliseconds) string, b contains the text that is typed after the 10 milliseconds.
long m=0;                        // Store the start milliseconds in variable m
void setup() {
  size(9,9);                     // set the dimensions of the window
}

void draw() {                    // loop forever
  m=m<1?millis():m;              // update m
  println(b+a);                  // print the string b+a
}

void keyTyped() {                // this function gets called whenever a key is typed
  if(millis() - m) >9)           // if over 9 milliseconds have elapsed then
    b+=key;                      //   add the key to the end of b
  else                           // else (if less than 10 milliseconds have elapsed)
    a=key+a;                     //   prepend the key to a
}
```

Comment: @WheatWizard Say the input was `asdf` + `ghjk`. If everything was in one variable, then after the 10 milliseconds, we would have `fdsa` in that one string. After that, when `g` is typed, the string will prepend the `g` and become `gfdsa`. Then when the `h` is typed, I cannot prepend `h` to the variable (because then the input is still reversed), I will need to use `substring`s and have to calculate the `length` of that String variable. This  will cost a lot of bytes.

Comment: use ternary to reduce bytes

Comment: @Mr.Alien In order to use a ternary, I would need to deal with the same variable, but here, I am use two different variables (namely `a` and `b`). Even if I assign the result to a temp variable, the resulting bytecount is still larger.

Comment: My bad, I thought it's a JavaScript answer x) .. realized when I saw type casting in your answer...

Answer (score 1):

## C - 169 bytes

Well C is not the best for this as it has no platform-independent way of doing this. Works under MSVC.

```
#include<time.h>
#include<conio.h>
l,k,b[9];main(a){for(a=clock();clock()-a<100;(k=_getch())?b[l++]=k:0);for(;(k=_getch())-13;k?putchar(k):0);for(;l;putchar(b[--l]));}
```

Bit of a hacky approach, if you can type more than 9 characters in 10 ms, this will crash. Updates after a newline character.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can mash 9 random characters in 10ms...

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>112</s> 106

```python
import msvcrt as m,time
a=b=''
T=time.time
t=T()
while 1:c=m.getch();exec'ba=+c=+cb'[T()-t>1::2];print a+b
```

If you want the output to be flush, without flooding with lines, use `print'\r'+a+b,` instead

You'll need to kill the process to stop it